# 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I have a function below that parse data from Yahoo Finance then write to a cvs file. `data_scrapper` return a plain html with provided `symbol`.
I got an error:

```
Exception Value:    'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
Exception Location: ./finance_parser/views.py in button_clicked, line 76
```

Line 76 refer to this line: `headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]`

```
def button_clicked(request):

    rows = []
    current_url = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
    symbol = current_url[-4:-1].replace('%20', ' ')
    gen_table = data_scrapper(symbol)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(gen_table)
    table = soup.findAll('table')
    headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        rows.append([val.text for val in row.findAll('td')])

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "{}.csv"'.format(symbol)

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)

    return response
```

Comment: Your request may be wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table = soup.findAll('table') # Here is set of tables
```

You need iterate through tables (ResultSet)

```
headers = []
for table in soup.findAll('table'):
   headers.extend([header.text for header in table.find_all('th')])
```